# How to pop to root view controller on UITabBarItem switch?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` with two `UINavigationController`, when I switch from one `TabBarItem` to other, the previously selected view controller should pop to its root view controller.

Answer (score 7):

Implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController)` method like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
   if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
       navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
   }
   return true
}
```